# The generally accepted way to do bulk product importing in a Shopify App

Tags: graphql, shopify-app

I'm currently working on my first Shopify app and it requires bulk importing products. I'm looking around the web, and it appears there's no query to do bulk importing. It also looks like if I want to add the price to the items I import, I'll have to make a separate query from the one that creates the products in the first place.

I'm thinking the easier way would be to create a .csv but there's no query to upload a .csv either.

Has anyone tackled something like this before, and what's the usual way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not supported then **standard graphql possibilities** [possibly (not tested)] can (should be possible) be applied:

### Aliases

You can make **multiple queries/mutations within one request.**

### Guaranteed order of mutations on root level

Multiple (aliased) chains of mutations:

- m1a: insert #1,
- m1b: define #1 price,
- m2a: insert #2,
- m2b: define #2 price
  ...

Probably you can use arguments used for element creation (one mutation) to search item for following mutation (if id not required).

**You can try/check this scenario in the playground.**

Of course in this case you need to construct query dynamically (usually not advised) in the app. You will need dynamic aliases and input variable names.